# NoSuchMethodError - org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL.parseURL

Tags: java, classpath, hsqldb

When using hsql for running test I'm getting this exception:

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL.parseURL(Ljava/lang/String; ZZ)Lorg/hsqldb/persist/HsqlProperties
```

I found this problem in another post which links to a solution which says it's a clash between jar of version 1.8 and another of version 2.2.5.
I checked the project's libraries and the `.classpath` and it only has 1.8. Also I deleted this from the classpath and still got the same exception.

Still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Use the same classpath libraries at both compile time and run time, the error will get off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're compiling with a later version of the library, and running it with an earlier version.

The method that exists at compile time doesn't exist at runtime -> NoSuchMethodError.

Solution: Use the same library at runtime.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: By examining the runtime classpath, whatever that may be.

Comment: Do you have any idea how could this be happening if I'm compiling and building the eclipse project with maven?

Comment: @Avi Check the version of your dependency and its scope. I'm betting the scope isn't runtime.

Comment: That seems to be the correct way. We still have some invstigation to do but it seems that we had some clashes in our pom.xml files.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you use maven (as you mentioned you do) project it's possible that you inherit something from the pom.xml and override it in one of your project's dependencies which can lead to a clash.

Notice that for `hsql` the maven group id was changed from `hsqldb` to `org.hsqldb` which might make it easy to let these 2 jars live together in the same project and cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with assembly shading in `build.sbt`:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("org.hsqldb.**" -> "shade-hsqldb.@1").inAll
)
```